# Copy subfolders with exclusions

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, copy

I have a messy situation on production server, there is a location on production which should only contain 3 folder however due to not following some process we have got more than 1000 folders and files and I am aiming to clean it via a batch file so that there is no chances of human error.

So I would like to copy all folders and files except 3 folders to a new location. can someone help in this as not able to put logic to exclude these 3 folders.

Comment: First when you say "copy" it sounds like you really mean "move"? Secondly, what have you attempted so far? SO isn't a coding service. We'd love to help you, but not necessarily do it for you.

Comment: Include the paths and foldernames of the three folders.

Comment: @dman2306 thanks for your feedback will keep it in mind! :)

Comment: @foxidrive three folders are testenv,stageenv and prodenv the other folders are name patterns are like {yyyy-dd-mm}_testenv,{yyyy-dd-mm}_stageen,{yyyy-dd-mm}_prodenv

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called `ex.txt` that includes 3 lines, each of which is the name of the folder that you would like to exclude from the copy, e.g.:

```
\folder1\
\folder2\
\folder3\
```

Now, go to the parent of the high-level directory (say, `directory_to_copy`), that you would like to copy, in which location exists the ex.txt file, and type

```
xcopy /e /i /exclude:ex.txt directory_to_copy destination_name
```

This will exclude the folders `folder1`, `folder2`, and `folder3` from the copy.

Note: the backslashes `\` are important to ensure that the other folders containing those strings (folder1, folder2, and folder3) are not excluded.

Answer (score 0):

This writes `tempmove.bat.txt` in the same folder as the batch file that contains the move commands to move every folder except the three folders shown (testenv stageenv prodenv).

You can examine the text file before renaming it to `.bat` to actually use, if it shows the right commands.

Make sure `"d:\wrong folders"` folder already exists.

```
@echo off
cd /d "c:\production folder"
(
for /d %%a in (*) do (
  if /i not "%%~nxa"=="testenv" if /i not "%%~nxa"=="stageenv" if /i not "%%~nxa"=="prodenv" echo move "%%~fa" "d:\wrong folders\%%~nxa"
)
)>"%~dp0\tempmove.bat.txt"
pause
```

Comment: thanks mate but somehow its not working, the output file is not generated as well

Comment: That was my error - see the changed code and comments.